# How do I use a shader without changing original color

Tags: c++, shader, sfml

I have a text class that displays numbers in a colored font. When I am not using my shader, some of the text displays in light green, and other text displays in white, by design. When I use the shader, All text is white. I'm pretty sure the reason for this is because in shader.frag i have rgb as vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, opacity); 
I do not, however, know how to have these values changed for some types of text, and not changed for others. What I want to do is maintain the original color of text, and slowly reduce opacity. How can this code be modified to do this?
Here is my code containing the implementation of this:

shader.frag:

```
uniform sampler2D texture;
uniform float opacity;

void main()
{
vec4 pixel = texture2D(texture, gl_TexCoord[0].xy);
gl_FragColor = pixel * vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, opacity);
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

shader.vert:

```
void main()

{

gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;

gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_TextureMatrix[0] * gl_MultiTexCoord0;

gl_FrontColor = gl_Color;

}
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

application of shader in main function:

```
sf::Shader shader;

if (!shader.loadFromFile("shader.vert", "shader.frag"))

return EXIT_FAILURE;

float opacity = 1.0; //transparency of shader

shader.setParameter("texture", sf::Shader::CurrentTexture); //shader.vert

shader.setParameter("opacity", opacity);                    //shader.frag
```

///////////////////////////

////////////////////////////

////////////////////////////

//Delete Text Display

```
counter1 = 0;

for (iter8 = textDisplayArray.begin(); iter8 != textDisplayArray.end(); 
iter8++)

{

    if (textDisplayArray[counter1].destroy == true)

    {
        //shader

        opacity -= 0.1;  

        if (opacity <= 0)

        {

            textDisplayArray.erase(iter8);

            opacity = 1;

        }

        shader.setParameter("opacity", opacity);

    }
```

Comment: We can't change your post to properly format your code. You have to format your code properly with Markdown. Or failing that, select it and press the "code" toolbar button.

Comment: fixed it, any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use **`gl_Color`** in your fragment shader:

*shader.frag:*

```
uniform sampler2D texture;
uniform float opacity;

void main()
{
    vec4 pixel   = texture2D(texture, gl_TexCoord[0].xy);
    gl_FragColor = pixel * vec4( gl_Color.rgb, opacity );
                              // ^        ^^^ RGB-color passed by vertex shader
}
```

**shader.vert:**

```
void main()
{
    gl_Position    = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
    gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_TextureMatrix[0] * gl_MultiTexCoord0;
    gl_FrontColor  = gl_Color;
    gl_BackColor   = gl_Color;
}
```